# how to make dynamic rowspan codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have table rowspan dynamic in my view like this :

```
<tr> 
<?php $no = 1;
foreach($idn as $ia){?>
  <td width="17" align="center"  >E</td>
  <td width="134" align="left"  colspan="2" >Indikator Kinerja Jabatan </td>
  <td colspan="4"   align="left" bordercolor="#FFFFFF"  > <p>
  <?php echo $no++ ?>.
  <?php echo $ia->indikator_kompetensi; ?><br/>
  </p></td>
```

this result of my code
[image: my result]

how to make like this
[image: this what i want]

Comment: Why would you need a rowspan? You can just put all the data in the same TD?

Comment: show your tables

Answer (score 0):

Make a group before putting into `foreach` to display in html

```
<?php
$yourArr = [
  ["id"=>1,"name"=>"name1","desc"=>"description1"],
  ["id"=>1,"name"=>"name1","desc"=>"description2"],
  ["id"=>2,"name"=>"name2","desc"=>"description3"],
  ["id"=>2,"name"=>"name2","desc"=>"description4"],
];
print_r($yourArr);
$neededArr = array();
foreach($yourArr as $k=>$v){
 $neededArr[$v['id']]["name"] = $v["name"];
 $neededArr[$v['id']]["child"][] = ["desc"=>$v["desc"]];
}
print_r($neededArr);
?>
```

[Live Demo](https://eval.in/1051810)

[Graphical View](https://eval.in/1051826)

Program Output :

```
name1       description1        
            description2        
-----------------------------------
name2       description3        
            description4        
-----------------------------------
```

Comment: what should I do first

Comment: @MelvinArioWitama you should group your List by **Indikator Kinerja Jabatan**

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can take all  outside of for-each & inside a last  use for-each for showing data.

```
<tr> 
<?php $no = 1;
  <td width="17" align="center"  >E</td>
  <td width="134" align="left">Indikator Kinerja Jabatan </td>
  <td align="left" bordercolor="#FFFFFF"  ><p> 
foreach($idn as $ia){?>
  echo $no . $ia->indikator_kompetensi . '<br/>';
  $no++; 
}
?>
</p></td>
<tr>
```

Comment: still cant what should i do

Comment: I just updated the answer, You can get your output without the count as well.

Answer (score 0):

this is answer from my question

```
<tr> 

           <td width="17" align="center"  >E</td>
            <td width="134" align="left"  colspan="2" >Indikator Kinerja Jabatan </td>

              <td colspan="4"   align="left" bordercolor="#FFFFFF"  > <p>
              <?php $no = 1;
foreach($idn as $ia){?>
             <?php echo $no++ ?>.
              <?php echo $ia->indikator_kompetensi; ?><br/>
                             <?php } ?>               </p></td>


</tr>
```

thankyou everyone for helping me